# 404 returned from GET method with query parameters

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I am using *RestAssured* *2.7.0* to automate rest APIs. I am unable to get a response for my GET method with query parameters.

the request is `http://localhost:81/rest/services/user?firstName=john.`

I tried it with query parameter i.e.,

```
given().queryParam("firstName","john").when().get(API);
```

But I'm getting a `404 Not found` response.

Thanks Inadvance.

Comment: Would you be able to provide more of the code and exact error messages, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

404 error is nothing to do with Get Parameters, but the HttpStatus code mentions that I didnt find the rest service you are looking for.

Try the `http://localhost:81/rest/services/user?firstName=john` service in any REST clients like `Postman` or `Advanced Rest Client` and see if you are getting correct response.

Three scenarios I can think of right now:

1. You are pointing to a wrong server
2. REST service is not deployed on the server
3. Server is not started

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

I got solution for this using addQueryParam()i.e.,

```
String API = "/user?firstName=john";
requestSpec = builder.addQueryParam("firstName", "john").build();
response = RestUtil.basicAuthRequest().spec(request).when().get(API);
```